# How do I select distinct count over multiple columns?

Tags: db2, mainframe

How to select distinct count over multiple columns?

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT col1, col2, col3) FROM table;
```

Is there a working equivalent of this in DB2?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are multiple options:

```
select count(*) from
   (select distinct col1, col2, col3 FROM table) t
```

The other would be to combine the columns via a CONCAT:

```
select count(distinct col1 || col2 || col3) from table
```

The first option is the cleaner (and likely faster) one.

Comment: The first option doesn't work in DB2 . The second one works fine, thank you.

Comment: There was a typo in the first which I fixed.

Comment: ...concatenating the columns may yield surprising results (for example, rows with `(11,1,1)` and `(1, 1, 11)`), so you at minimum need to know something about your domain, and will almost always require a separator be added.  Plus the concatenation will be slow on a table of any real size.  @user2329435 - what do you mean "doesn't work"?  That's the proper way to structure that type of query.

Comment: `select count(*) from (select distinct col1, col2, col3 FROM table) as correlationname`  works.

Comment: Which platform / version of Db2? My version is on LUW

Comment: +1 for concatenation, which also works in a larger query with other summary statistitics (e.g. `select count(*), count(distinct(*)), count(distinct col1 || col2 || col3) from table`).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse At which size do you expect performance problems? For me, concatenation still works ok for ~ 300,000 rows, which, to me, looks like a "real size."

Answer (score 3):

```
select count(distinct col1 || '^' || col2 || '^' || col3) from table
```

to avoid problems during concatenation like between 1 || 11 which would be the same as 11 || 1.